# yii2 Unknown Property

Tags: php, windows, xampp, yii2, yii2-basic-app

following the example(2nd video) at [Yii2 Screencasts](http://www.yiiframework.com/screencasts/)

I have created a controller GreetingController with Gii as follows:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class GreetingController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public $message = 'Message variable from Controller';
    public $message2 = 'Message2 variable from Controller2';

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index',array('content'=>$this->message));
    }

}
```

And View with this code listing:

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;

echo $content;
echo $this->message2;
?>
<h1>greeting/index</h1>

<p>
    You may change the content of this page by modifying
    the file <code><?= __FILE__; ?></code>.
</p>
```

What I am trying here is to access the variables from controller class. I am getting Unknown Property Error on line:

```
echo $this->message2;
```

If I removed this line, It will successfully display the value of the $content variable. Because in the view tutorial I mentioned above, there are 2 ways we can pass data from controller to view, first method is working fine if we pass variables in array. But when I try to access a public variable directly from view, I am getting this error. Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what does var_dump($this) output?

Comment: it outputs a massive text, spanning whole page or two.

Comment: Please http://pastebin.com/ it

Comment: Have you tried if `echo $this->message;` works? (message instead of message2)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FjrK2EUJ,  but this is only first part, as there is some limit of text characters. If you need I will paste the later text in parts.

Comment: yes I tried that also. it did not worked.

Comment: Try `$this->context->message2`

Comment: thanks @bpoiss. it works this way.

Comment: But I could not understand why this is not discussed in the video, also I saw this example http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-hello.html, but did not mentioned this trick.

Comment: In this example the variable is also passed via the render method, and I would recommend you always to use this method to pass variables to your view, and never access them directly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming) for detailed information about why this is best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access public variables directly, you have to use your objects context variable.

```
$this->context->yourVariable
```

So in your case:

```
$this->context->message2
```

Comment: Thanks @bpoiss, helping me to get rid of this problem :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Yes I agree, this is not the best practice. But I just want to follow the available 2 methods for passing data from controller to view. Just trying to make sure I could use both ways :)